# Replacing Class with variable

Tags: jquery

Just a simple question,

Im trying to replace class with var, but obviously still something wrong in the string.

I'm doing this:

```
var C = $('.form')         

    $(" ' " + C + "' tr").remove();
```

and trying to achieve this:

```
$(".form tr").remove();
```

I know that might be simple question, but please forgive me, Im still learning basics

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as easy as:

```
var C = $('.form') 
c.find('tr').remove();
```

but you might do this too (maybe slower in some cases)

```
var c = ".form";
$(c + ' tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var C = ".form";
$(C + " tr").remove();
```